# overcoming these TS errors in useQuery?

Tags: react-query

So, this is not obvious to me. I am expecting to return this:

data: {
totalPrice: string;
}

and yet, I'm getting a mismatch between a Promise and QueryFunction....

I'm creating a custom query hook...

```
  return useQuery<AddSkuSelectedSku['totalPrice'], Error>(
    [queryKey, item],
    async () => {
      const { data } = await product.price({ item })

      return {
        totalPrice: data?.price || ''
      }
    }, mergedOptions
  );
```

I'm seeing this same type of error in which my QueryFunction is bunking out.

Is it because I am using an 'async function' as the second argument?
[image]

And because of this, the files I am using are giving TS error as the returned type is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `queryFn` argument expects a return type of a `string` or a `Promise<string>`. An `async` method returns a `Promise<T>`, so you're almost there.

Instead of returning `{ totalPrice: data?.price || '' }`, you should return `data?.price || ''`, assuming `data?.price` is a string.

Comment: But to answer OP's request to return `data: { totalPrice: string; }` you'd change the type of the `useQuery` to `Pick<AddSkuSelectedSku, 'totalPrice'>`.

Comment: I'm a friggin bonehead :-) makes complete sense and can't believe I missed it.